# Count number of message/event in Kafka stream at a periodic level

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have created one Kafka stream by consuming the message from one Kafka topic. I want to count what is the number of messages that I have received at a **1-minute level**.

So let's say, I have got the message in the following way:

```
t1 -> message1
t1 -> message2
t1 -> message3
```

After 1 minute I receive the message say like this

```
t2 -> message4
t2 -> message5
```

Let's say I have one integer variable `count` in my Java application. What I want is from the start of the application till 1 minute this count value should be 3. At the end of the second minute, this count variable should become 2. This is because at the first minute I Had received 3 messages and in the second minute I had received 2 messages.

My code so far

```
import lombok.SneakyThrows;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serde;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsBuilder;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.Topology;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Consumed;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.ForeachAction;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KStream;

import java.util.Properties;

public class CountMessage {
    private static KafkaStreams kafkaStreams;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "my_first_count_2");
        props.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "10.0.0.43:9092");
        props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());
        props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.Long().getClass());
        props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_TIMESTAMP_EXTRACTOR_CLASS_CONFIG, MyTimestampExtractor.class);

        final StreamsBuilder streamsBuilder = new StreamsBuilder();
        

        // consuming stream
        String kafkaTopic = "my_kafka_topic_2";

        System.out.println("Starting the application");
        KStream<String, String> myStream = streamsBuilder
                .stream(kafkaTopic);

        myStream.foreach(new ForeachAction<String, String>() {
            @SneakyThrows
            @Override
            public void apply(String key, String value) {
                System.out.println("key received = " + key + "---<<<" + value);
            }
        });

        final Topology topology = streamsBuilder.build();
        kafkaStreams = new KafkaStreams(topology, props);
        kafkaStreams.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you're tied to using Kafka Streams, but for what it's worth you can do this with ksqlDB:

```sql
SELECT TIMESTAMPTOSTRING(WINDOWSTART,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') AS TS, 
       COUNT(*) AS MSG_COUNT 
FROM   SRC_STREAM 
         WINDOW TUMBLING (SIZE 1 MINUTE) 
GROUP BY 'X' 
EMIT CHANGES;
```